# How to display Advanced custom field data in new order email in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have advanced custom field plugin and i have added a custom field to my product the label name is (stock_number) my question is how do it display/show this field data in the new order email.

Comment: I have checked this and the code is not working it says internel server error when placing an order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code should do the trick.

**Option1:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 'ts_order_item_meta_start', 10, 4 );
function ts_order_item_meta_start( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {

    if( $stock_number = get_field( 'stock_number', $item->get_product_id() ) ;
        echo $stock_number;
}
```

**Option2:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'display_stock_email_order_details', 10, 4 );

function display_stock_email_order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if( $stock_number = get_field( "stock_number", $item->get_product_id() ) ){
            echo '<p><strong>'.__('Stock Number').': </strong>'.$stock_number.'</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

**Option3:**

The below code will replace the Product Title with the ACF Custom Value.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'custom_order_item_name', 10, 2 );
function custom_order_item_name( $item_name, $item ) {
    // Targeting email notifications only
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url() ) 
        return $item_name;

    // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
    $product = $item->get_product();

    if( $stock_number = get_field('stock_number', $product->get_id()) ) {
        $item_name = '<p class="item-stck" style="margin:12px 0 0;">
        <strong>' . __( 'Stock Number', 'woocommerce' ) . ': </strong>' . $stock_number . '</p>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

**Option4:**

The below code will replace the Product Name with your custom field.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'custom_order_item_name', 10, 2 );
function custom_order_item_name( $item_name, $item ) {

    // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
    $product = $item->get_product();

    if( $stock_number = get_field('stock_number', $product->get_id()) ) {
        $item_name = '<p class="item-stck" style="margin:12px 0 0;">
        <strong>' . __( 'Stock Number', 'woocommerce' ) . ': </strong>' . $stock_number . '</p>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

Comment: Hi the option 2 did work bt one little problem it displays the stock number above the order number i want it to display below or replace title/name of the product

Comment: you want to remove the title of the product?

Comment: Just noticed that this code only replaced the product title with stock number in the email, not in the order confirmation page and orders.

Comment: Yes but what I am saying is how can I do that change the title in the orders as well

Comment: Updated the answer. Try Option 4 and see it if works.

Comment: i have another question you can find it in the link below if you can answer that would be great. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60188986/how-to-change-product-title-with-custom-field-in-the-order-review-section-on-the

Comment: Will check. Kindly post the question in detail along with Screenshots for better understanding

Comment: Hi @Rajeev could you help me with one more modification. we replaced the product title with the stock_number how can we do that in the admin email we leave both product title and stock_number

Comment: You want to remove Title and Stock Number from Admin email?

Comment: no i want to have both in just admin email title and stock_number so i want the product title to only appear in admin email

Comment: Now where all the title and stock_number is appearing?

Comment: you remember in the above code we replace product title with stock number in the new order emails and on the orders page so i want the product title to only appear in the new orders admin email

Comment: Hi i have another question if you could answer, please  https://stackoverflow.com/q/60392821/7998191

Comment: Hi i have used your option it was working fine until the other day now i am getting an error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on bool in functions.php on line 271 line 271 is if( $stock_number = get_field('stock_number', $product->get_id()) ) {