# How to change product title with custom field in the order review section on the checkout page in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

How to change product title with a custom field in the order review section on the checkout page in woocommerce. i have an advanced custom field stock_number i want to change the product title with stock_number field in the product review on the checkout page.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the section where you would like to change?

Comment: checkout page order review section this is the function Function woocommerce_order_review

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the SS of that page?

Comment: when you press view cart button and then proceed to checkout button after the is the checkout page and that is where the order review with all the other fields for the address name etc

Answer (score 2):

```
function woocommerce_update_product_title($title, $cart_item){
    if( is_checkout() || is_cart() ) : //Check Checkout or Cart Page
        $stock_number = get_post_meta($cart_item['product_id'], 'stock_number',true);
        return !empty( $stock_number ) ? $stock_number : $title;        
    endif;
    return $title;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'woocommerce_update_product_title', 10, 2);
```

Please try this code which could help you

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207802/discussion-on-answer-by-krunal-prajapati-how-to-change-product-title-with-custom).

Answer (score 1):

To have full control over this, you can directly edit the template files and alter the product title.

Copy the template file from the path of your website and paste it inside your themes folder.

Copy the file from:

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php

Paste it to:

wp-content/themes/themename/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php

**Replace the below code:**

```
<th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
```

**New Code:**

```
<?php $stock_number = get_field('stock_number', $product_id); ?>
<th class="product-name"><?php echo $stock_number; ?></th>
```

Comment: and what do i change there?

Comment: You may do that on line number 38 in `review-order.php` and on line number 80 & 82 in `cart.php` you may find these file in woocommerce plugin

Comment: Updated my answer.